# Skip pdfs scraping httpClient c#

Tags: c#, pdf, httpclient, screen-scraping

When I'm scraping and find a URL that is a pdf the application stops. How can I do to omit the urls that are PDF?

```
public string SendWebRequestSinProxy(string url)
    {          
            //controlarTiempos("SendWebRequestSinProxy(string url)");                
            string result = "";
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {                
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");                
            client.Timeout.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

                 using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                 {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {                                
                            result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        }
                  }
            }            
        return result;
    }
```

Thank you very much for your answers to the future

Comment: I mean the application goes into pause mode and it can take several minutes without doing anything

Comment: it is waiting. I am sorry. my english is very bad.

Comment: Example the return:  
  
  http://www.bibliotecavirtualdeandalucia.es/catalogo/catalogo_imagenes/imagen_id.cmd?idImagen=4900225
El subproceso 0x22a0 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0x1978 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0x2140 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0xef0 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0x1218 terminó con código 0 (0x0).